# Bid - Ask / red or green / Level 2 questions

Tags: stocks, trading

My question comes just after this [questions](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/1063/can-someone-explain-a-stocks-bid-vs-ask-price-relative-to-current-price). That was well answered by the community.

[image: ToS level 2]

Please, correct any wrong interpretation. This is for ToS, but I guess it could help any similar questions for other platforms

1) that 2.5810 is the last trade, is this correct?

1.1) ToS has two apparently redundant information. (in the picture, #1, to the right and to the left). Is this correct?

2) 2.1) +231 - can't figure it out. Base points?

2.2) +9.83 - probably the % change for today.

3) Bid and Ask. It does not matter whether bid > ask or ask > bid, I see red and green regardless of prices or comparisons. What does red and green mean?

4) Again, it may be red, green and white.

4.1 Without details, those symbols represent different markets. I have tried for a couple of days how to have only US markets (all). Not success here for this very simple problem.

4.2 Bid/ask: There are green (probably positive growth), red (negative) and white (well, the leftover is no movement, neither up or down). Is this interpretation correct for the white?

5) BS and AS. Number of shares at that price with that specific price? People buying just 1? Well, it may be truth fo appl and goog.

I have been using ToS for a few days, and the learning curve is steep. I tested several platforms, and this one seems to have a lot of tools, but being user-friendly is not its main asset.

I could move around and even create formulas with all the other platforms (expect Fidelity) in a matter of a few days. This... I can't even find an option: all US markets.
Any help will be greatly appreciated.

PS. I thought this group is the most appropriate one for my question. Feel free to point to the right direction. I couldn't find the right tags.

Comment: You should break your question into multiple individual questions, as you are covering a lot of topics here.

Comment: I don't need an explanation of each question. It's just like as it was answered. Straight to the point and then I can search the individual concepts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> that 2.5810 is the last trade, is this correct?

Most likely. Some providers may use the midpoint of the bid/ask spread, but most likely it is the level of the last executed trade.

> ToS has two apparently redundant information. (in the picture, #1). Is this correct?

I have no idea why it's shown twice.

> +231 - can't figure it out. Base points? ... +9.83 - probably the % change for today.

If you look closely, it's actually +.231, which seems to be the change in price today. If you back it out, the "starting" price was 2.581 - 0.231 - 2.35. 0.231 is 9.83% of 2.35, indicating that the price has increased 0.231, or 9.83% today.

> Bid and Ask. It does not matter whether bid > ask or ask > bid, I see red and green regardless of prices or comparisons. What does red and green mean?

ask will always be greater than bid, so the red and green indicate upward or downward movements from the last value.

> Bid/ask: There are green (probably positive growth), red (negative) and white (well, the leftover is no movement, neither up or down). Is this interpretation correct for the white?

Again, typically red means a downward movement, which could be from the last point or for the day. Since the price is green indicating a increase for the day, most likely the red numbers indicate a downward change *from the last bid/ask amounts*. White would indicate no change.

> BS and AS. Number of shares at that price with that specific price? People buying just 1? Well, it may be truth fo appl and goog.

It's most likely number of *units* which is typically 100 shares, but might be different for different instruments or on different exchanges.

Comment: Thank you so much. The number 1 in the picture has the same information to the right and to the left. It seems to be always the same,

Comment: "ask will always be greater than bid".  It's an infrequent occurrence but occasionally, the ask is lower than the bid and that is called a crossed market.

Answer (score 1):

(1+2) Last trade is $2.581, up 23.1 cents (9.83%).
Unless there's a header explaining otherwise, I would assume that the information is redundant.

(3) Green means an uptick, red means a down tick and white  means unchanged

(4) The names listed are for different exchanges and ECNs, all of which quote  this stock.
If the bid or asked price is red, it means that it's a down tick (green for up tick).

(5) Size numbers represent 100's of shares offered, rounded down to the nearest 100.  If I bid for 200 shares at $2.57 and I am the only bidder at that price, the bid size will be 2.  If I was trying to buy 357 shares, my buy size would be displayed as 3.

The bid  for EDGX is $2.58 with a size of 8 (800 to 899 shares).  The bid price is white (unchanged) but the bid size is red which means that the size on EDGX at that price decreased since the last trade there.

No competent trading platform is user friendly because they now offer layer upon layer of sophisticated tools.  I'd suggest that you utilize their virtual trader (if not already doing so) so that you can explore the platform, create orders, stop algos, option orders, or  anything else that interests you without having the fear of placing an inadvertent trade.